# Store query result as php variable

Tags: php, mysql

Before you spam as duplicate I have read through around 20-30 posts on this site about how to do this as well as others and I can't get mine to work so thats why i am asking the question.

I have the following code:

```
$lookupID = "SELECT ID FROM dungeon WHERE Name = '$loc'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $lookupID);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$locID = $row['ID'];

$query = "INSERT INTO boss (ID, Name, Type, Location, LocationID, Difficulty) VALUES ('0', '$boss', '$type', '$loc', '$locID', '$diff')";
```

The purpose for the lookupID is to based upon the $loc value lookup in the other table what the locID value associated with it is and set $locID to that number. Currently when I run the query I get the following:

```
Error: INSERT INTO boss (ID, Name, Type, Location, LocationID, Difficulty) VALUES ('0', 'Godzilla', 'Lizard', 'Black Rock Hold', '', '4')
```

With the locID variable giving no value and so causing the error. Im sure its something simple and stupid I am doing but I am new to php and mysql so I hope you forgive me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row) function returns the array with enumerated keys, so you should use

```
$locID = $row[0];
```

If you want, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to get the row with associative keys instead.

Comment: Thank you I knew it had to be something simple! +1

Comment: Had to wait for the timer to go before I could :)